# Hadoop startup issue on Mac Os

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

Running start-all.sh script on MacBook i can see that error

```
2013-12-01 17:23:44.024 java[11279:f13] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xe807, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

And seems like hdfs is not started up

What may be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the exact same issue...

Comment: Well, i did, i presented my Mac to my wife and bought Asus, removed Win 8 and setup the Arch Linux. :)